# Trying to connect with sql server database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to connect sql server with php, i'm trying to get info from the database..
Now, here is what i got:

```
 try {
    $user = '';
    $pass = '';
    $objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=192.168.10.250;dbname=WEB_POROSIA',
    '$user', '$pass');
    $objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

    $sql = "SELECT *    
            FROM 'WEB_POROSIA'
           ";
    $statement = $objDb->query($sql);
    $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();

     }
```

I receive this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

This is my first attempt to connect php with sql server, and i don't know what this output means, i mean i don't know what might cause it!

I'm using xampp.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to connect using the wrong driver.

For Sql Server you might want to use PDO ODBC driver not the mysql method you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different DBO driver.
Check out other ODBC drivers, i.e PDO.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written tries to connect to a MySQL database rather than a MSSQL one.

You'll want to do something like this:

```
$db_connection = new PDO("dblib:dbname=$db_name;host=$host", $username, $password);
```

You can find more information here: http://grover.open2space.com/content/use-php-and-pdo-connect-ms-sql-server